# Stm32f303k8 Comparator register address?

Tags: microcontroller, cpu-registers, stm32f3

I am rather new to uC programming and have hit a wall trying to find the base register address of comparator peripherals for the stm32f303k8. I couldn't find the info in either the reference manual, datasheet, or programming manual, as well as many other hits on various searches. 
I've seen that if a clock is enabled for the comparators it runs on the AHB clock, but a separate diagram shows the AHB feeding into both APB1 and APB2 and the comparators were specifically placed under the APB2. I am quite confused and would welcome any help (short of using libraries!), even a search string pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The answer given is the most correct one, but you can also find the base addresses by searching in the HAL headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the answer in the
[reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00043574-stm32f303xbcde-stm32f303x68-stm32f328x8-stm32f358xc-stm32f398xe-advanced-armbased-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
of your **STM32F303k8** rather than in its
[datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303k8.pdf).

In section 3.2.2 of the reference manual, you find both the relation between the peripherals and the buses through which you can reach them, and the boundary/base addresses of the peripheral registers. 
On Table 4 on pages 57/58 is for your controller subfamily.
Here, I find a line on *SYSCFG + COMP + OPAMP*, which may be what you are looking for. Base address for all is **0x4001 0000**, connection is through APB2.

**Edit:**
If you want to check the documentation which buses/clocks are needed along the way to drive the peripheral, I recommend starting at Fig. 1 in Ch. 2 (p. 13) of the datasheet. Here, you find that APB2 is driven through AHB2, and that COMPs are configured through SYSCFG CTL. The clock tree depicted in Fig. 2 in Sec. 3.6 (p. 19) shows that APB2 clock is driven (with another prescaler) by the AHB clock (HCLK). The details are described in Ch. 2 of the reference manual.

I personally prefer to start with the clock tree editor tool embedded to STM32CubeMX because I feel too lazy to look up all the information at the beginning of development. This gives one the chance to start from a reasonable guess and verify if the clock settings are the needed ones afterwards.

Comment: Name checks out. Thanks! I had searched in the reference using the string "comp" but after seeing hundreds of hits or so I tried "comparator". Unfortunately this glossed right over the info you just provided. I have learned something.

Comment: (-: You're welcome! If the answer solved the problem, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and consider [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it.

Comment: Um, I'm new here as well. I think the green check mark is accepting the answer? Clicked it at any rate. Unfortunately, I received a notification that I dont have enough reputation for the upvote to show but it has been recorded.